# Kubernetes - Create two containers in one pod

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes

I'm developing an application that consists of two containers. I want to deploy them in Kubernetes into one Pod, since I want the two services to be behind one IP address. However, I'm having a hard time trying to connect the Kubernetes Services with the containers.

How could I write a `deployment.yml` file, so that when the user calls a `x.x.x.x:port1`, the request is forwarded to the first container, and when the `x.x.x.x:port2` is called, the request is forwarded to the second container. How could I specify the Services?

Here's what I have until now:

```
apiVersion:v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my_app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: first_container
    image: first_image
  
  - name: second_container
    image: second_image
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
```

Comment: Usually you'll just want these to be separate Deployments with a separate Service from each.  You don't directly connect to the pods and whether they're the same or different IP addresses usually isn't relevant; connecting from outside the cluster is always "special" and usually involves a NodePort or LoadBalancer type Service.

Comment: Just to add to @DavidMaze - with two containers in the same pod. It's not possible to scale them independently. Unless the containers are tightly coupled, it's not recommended to have two containers in a single pod.

Answer (score 6):

In your containers section you need to define a containerPort for each:

```
  containers:
  - name: first_container
    image: first_image
    ports:
    - containerPort: port1
  - name: second_container
    image: second_image
    ports:
    - containerPort: port2
```

And then in the ports section of the service definition you need to point the targetPorts of the service at those ports like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272547/9705485

Comment: According to the K8S documentation here for the container ports - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#container-v1-core - `Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network.`